# How to find the coordinates of intersection points between a plane and the coordinate axes?

Tags: geometry

Can you please explain what I am supposed to do and why that is true?

The equation of the plane is $4x - 3y = 12$.

Is the $z$ coordinate always zero in this plane or not? I mean, it is, if its the 
XY-plane, but this doesn't seem to be the case?
Where does this plane cut the $x$-axis, $y$-axis and $z$-axis?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and you are constraining one of the coordinates, say $x$ by $x=\frac{12+3y}{4}$. $y$ and $z$ are free and hence the resulting space is a $2$-d subspace or a plane.

Comment: To find points of intersection, say with the $x$ axis, substitute $y=z=0$ and similarly for the $y$ axis. This plane does not cut the $z$ axis

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This picture should give you an idea of what the situation looks like in space. The three coordinate axes are shown with yellow arrows.

Comment: If a plane does not contain one of the parameters, in this case z, it doesn't mean that the z-value is always 0 right? 
Does it just mean that the plane never touches the z-axis?

Comment: Well, what about the equation: $ y = x $ , that goes right through the z-axis but the equation doesn't contain $z$ . But yes, on the first part of your question.

Comment: So what you are saying is that in 2d space y=x is a line, while in 3d space, its an infinite plane right?

Comment: Yes, in 2-d (plane) we have a line, in 3-d (space) we have a plane.

Comment: Thaaaank you so much :). You made me realise so much. Also, could you tell me, did you use any software for that image, or just did it yourself?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I use Grapher which is in the utilities file of a Macintosh. If you have access to one you should try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically $z$, in the equation $4x-3y=12$ has the potential to be any point. Since we are given an equation with $x$ and $y$ only, and we are graphing this in $3$d space it is going to extend out to an infinite amount of $z$.